# I want to get user Profile Path in chrome through java script in my extension

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, profile

I have tried chrome.identity API it just gives the email and id for user.
I have also tried chrome:\version the path is written there but can't access that in so indirect way.
Is there any chrome API or other windows variable or anything that can help me in to get current user profile path.

Comment: There's no such API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.